# Parameter passing in Python vs Java

Tags: java, python

I am new to python trying to understand how parameters are passed in Python.

It shows everywhere that Python passes arguments by assignment.I am trying to compare it with Java.

How does it differ? It seems the same to me where everything is passed by value. Even in the case of references, it creates a copy of references and modification is done through it. I want to understand how it differs from Java.

I have attached a program where I was trying to understand how things are working out. It does the same even in Java.

```
def change(originalReferencecopy):
    originalReferencecopy.append(45)
    originalReferencecopy=[21, 44, 66, 89]
    print(originalReferencecopy)
    #output is [21, 44, 66, 89]


if __name__ == '__main__':
        original=[1,2,3,4,5]
        change(original)
        print(original)
        #output is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 45]
```

I want to understand the control flow of how things are working out for the above-mentioned program in python and java.

Comment: Python always passes a reference to functions. What you did in your code is to replace the reference with a new one by the assignment.

Comment: `append` acts on referenced parameter and assignment  changes the local variable.

Comment: Python and Java have the exact same evaluation strategy. Java has special-case primitive types, and considers everything else a "reference type". No such distinction exists in Python, and **everything** acts as a reference type.